# How to insert a svg image marker inside canvas image

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvas, google-maps-markers

I have a problem to solve. In my canvas image I put a marker but this is image type "png", I would like to have an icon svg so I can change the colour.

This code is working, i need to change .png with .svg, but doesn't work.

```
var Marker = function () {

    this.Sprite = new Image();
    this.Sprite.src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/O/e/P/x/i/map-marker-hi.png";
    this.Width = 20;
    this.Height = 32;
    this.XPos = 0;
    this.YPos = 0;
    this.textarea=null;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMjJU.png)

Answer (score -1):

Calling `ctx.drawImage` on load should do the trick. Drawing SVG files in this manner is supported on [all major modern browsers except for IE](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_canvasrenderingcontext2d_drawimage_svgimageelement_source_image)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

...

this.Sprite.onload = () => {
    ctx.drawImage(this.Sprite, 0, 0);
}
```

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45com0fa/)

[MDN `drawImage` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)

Comment: Yes, is good. But i need to call a svg html for some reason
<svg id="point" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" style="fill:#060;opacity:1" class="section bi bi-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="8"/></svg>..have some idea? Thank you